# Is it possible to use greek letters in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to render text containing letters from the Greek alphabet (instead of normal letters) using pygame fonts in pygame (python)?

Comment: Have you tried to do this?

Comment: I tried to use a raw string, similar to how I do it for pyplot, but it does not work. Couldn't find a way to do it on this site nor on Google.

Comment: maybe you're looking for _Unicode_ strings or any kind of Unicode support in PyGame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom fonts in pygame. Just find one that uses the Greek alphabet and use that. Use `pygame.font.SysFont()` and load your new font and enjoy.

Comment: It turned out to be as simple as that, thank you very much!